# How to format p-values in an association plot made with "vcd"?

Tags: r, plot

I made some multipanel association plots using cotabplot() and cotabc_coindep from the "vcd" package. This is an example using the Punishment data:

```
library("vcd")
data("Punishment", package = "vcd")

pun <- xtabs(Freq ~ memory + attitude + age + education, data = Punishment)

cotabplot(~ memory + attitude | age + education, data = pun, panel = 
cotab_coindep, n = 5000, type = "assoc", test = "maxchisq", interpolate = 
1:2, legend = T)
```

This is all working fine. But I'd like to format the p-values displayed in the legends on the side in such a way, that p-values, say in this example below 0.01, are displayed as p-value < 0.01.

I tried accessing the gpfun and even shading_hcl in order to format the p-values using format.pval() but this doesn't seem to work.

Does anybody know a way to format this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified `legend_resbased` and `shading_hcl` functions of `vcd` as follows:

```
legend_resbased <- structure(function (fontsize = 12, fontfamily = "", x = unit(1, 
    "lines"), y = unit(0.1, "npc"), height = unit(0.8, "npc"), 
    width = unit(0.7, "lines"), digits = 2, check_overlap = TRUE, 
    text = NULL, steps = 200, ticks = 10, pvalue = TRUE, range = NULL) 
{
    if (!is.unit(x)) 
        x <- unit(x, "native")
    if (!is.unit(y)) 
        y <- unit(y, "npc")
    if (!is.unit(width)) 
        width <- unit(width, "lines")
    if (!is.unit(height)) 
        height <- unit(height, "npc")
    function(residuals, shading, autotext) {
        res <- as.vector(residuals)
        if (is.null(text)) 
            text <- autotext
        p.value <- attr(shading, "p.value")
        legend <- attr(shading, "legend")
        if (all(residuals == 0)) {
            pushViewport(viewport(x = x, y = y, just = c("left", 
                "bottom"), default.units = "native", height = height, 
                width = width))
            grid.lines(y = 0.5)
            grid.text(0, x = unit(1, "npc") + unit(0.8, "lines"), 
                y = 0.5, gp = gpar(fontsize = fontsize, fontfamily = fontfamily))
            warning("All residuals are zero.")
        }
        else {
            if (is.null(range)) 
                range <- range(res)
            if (length(range) != 2) 
                stop("Range must have length two!")
            if (is.na(range[1])) 
                range[1] <- min(res)
            if (is.na(range[2])) 
                range[2] <- max(res)
            pushViewport(viewport(x = x, y = y, just = c("left", 
                "bottom"), yscale = range, default.units = "native", 
                height = height, width = width))
            if (is.null(legend$col.bins)) {
                col.bins <- seq(range[1], range[2], length = steps)
                at <- NULL
            }
            else {
                col.bins <- sort(unique(c(legend$col.bins, range)))
                col.bins <- col.bins[col.bins <= range[2] & col.bins >= 
                  range[1]]
                at <- col.bins
            }
            y.pos <- col.bins[-length(col.bins)]
            y.height <- diff(col.bins)
            grid.rect(x = unit(rep.int(0, length(y.pos)), "npc"), 
                y = y.pos, height = y.height, default.units = "native", 
                gp = gpar(fill = shading(y.pos + 0.5 * y.height)$fill, 
                  col = 0), just = c("left", "bottom"))
            grid.rect(gp = gpar(fill = "transparent"))
            if (is.null(at)) 
                at <- seq(from = head(col.bins, 1), to = tail(col.bins, 
                  1), length = ticks)
            lab <- format(round(at, digits = digits), nsmall = digits)
            tw <- lab[which.max(nchar(lab))]
            grid.text(format(signif(at, digits = digits)), x = unit(1, 
                "npc") + unit(0.8, "lines") + unit(1, "strwidth", 
                tw), y = at, default.units = "native", just = c("right", 
                "center"), gp = gpar(fontsize = fontsize, fontfamily = fontfamily), 
                check.overlap = check_overlap)
            grid.segments(x0 = unit(1, "npc"), x1 = unit(1, "npc") + 
                unit(0.5, "lines"), y0 = at, y1 = at, default.units = "native")
        }
        popViewport(1)
        grid.text(text, x = x, y = unit(1, "npc") - y + unit(1, 
            "lines"), gp = gpar(fontsize = fontsize, fontfamily = fontfamily, 
            lineheight = 0.8), just = c("left", "bottom"))
        if (!is.null(p.value) && pvalue) {
            grid.text(p.value, x = x, y = y - unit(1, "lines"), gp = gpar(fontsize = fontsize, 
                fontfamily = fontfamily, lineheight = 0.8), just = c("left", 
                "top"))
        }
    }
}, class = "grapcon_generator")


shading_hcl <- structure(function (observed, residuals = NULL, expected = NULL, 
    df = NULL, h = NULL, c = NULL, l = NULL, interpolate = c(2, 
        4), lty = 1, eps = NULL, line_col = "black", p.value = NULL, 
    level = 0.95, ...) 
{
    if (is.null(h)) 
        h <- c(260, 0)
    if (is.null(c)) 
        c <- c(100, 20)
    if (is.null(l)) 
        l <- c(90, 50)
    my.h <- rep(h, length.out = 2)
    my.c <- rep(c, length.out = 2)
    my.l <- rep(l, length.out = 2)
    lty <- rep(lty, length.out = 2)
    if (is.null(expected) && !is.null(residuals)) 
        stop("residuals without expected values specified")
    if (!is.null(expected) && is.null(df) && is.null(p.value)) {
        warning("no default inference available without degrees of freedom")
        p.value <- NA
    }
    if (is.null(expected) && !is.null(observed)) {
        expected <- loglin(observed, 1:length(dim(observed)), 
            fit = TRUE, print = FALSE)
        df <- expected$df
        expected <- expected$fit
    }
    if (is.null(residuals) && !is.null(observed)) 
        residuals <- (observed - expected)/sqrt(expected)
    if (is.null(p.value)) 
        p.value <- function(observed, residuals, expected, df) pchisq(sum(as.vector(residuals)^2), 
            df, lower.tail = FALSE)
    if (!is.function(p.value) && is.na(p.value)) {
        max.c <- my.c[1]
        p.value <- NULL
    }
    else {
        if (is.function(p.value)) 
            p.value <- p.value(observed, residuals, expected, 
                df)
        max.c <- ifelse(p.value < (1 - level), my.c[1], my.c[2])
    }
    if (!is.function(interpolate)) {
        col.bins <- sort(interpolate)
        interpolate <- stepfun(col.bins, seq(0, 1, length = length(col.bins) + 
            1))
        col.bins <- sort(unique(c(col.bins, 0, -col.bins)))
    }
    else {
        col.bins <- NULL
    }
    legend <- NULL
    if (!is.null(col.bins)) {
        res2 <- col.bins
        res2 <- c(head(res2, 1) - 1, res2[-1] - diff(res2)/2, 
            tail(res2, 1) + 1)
        legend.col <- hcl2hex(ifelse(res2 > 0, my.h[1], my.h[2]), 
            max.c * pmax(pmin(interpolate(abs(res2)), 1), 0), 
            my.l[1] + diff(my.l) * pmax(pmin(interpolate(abs(res2)), 
                1), 0), ...)
        lty.bins <- 0
        legend.lty <- lty[2:1]
        legend <- list(col = legend.col, col.bins = col.bins, 
            lty = legend.lty, lty.bins = lty.bins)
    }
    rval <- function(x) {
        res <- as.vector(x)
        fill <- hcl2hex(ifelse(res > 0, my.h[1], my.h[2]), max.c * 
            pmax(pmin(interpolate(abs(res)), 1), 0), my.l[1] + 
            diff(my.l) * pmax(pmin(interpolate(abs(res)), 1), 
                0), ...)
        dim(fill) <- dim(x)
        col <- rep(line_col, length.out = length(res))
        if (!is.null(eps)) {
            eps <- abs(eps)
            col[res > eps] <- hcl2hex(my.h[1], max.c, my.l[2], 
                ...)
            col[res < -eps] <- hcl2hex(my.h[2], max.c, my.l[2], 
                ...)
        }
        dim(col) <- dim(x)
        ltytmp <- ifelse(x > 0, lty[1], lty[2])
        if (!is.null(eps)) 
            ltytmp[abs(x) < abs(eps)] <- lty[1]
        dim(ltytmp) <- dim(x)
        return(structure(list(col = col, fill = fill, lty = ltytmp), 
            class = "gpar"))
    }
    attr(rval, "legend") <- legend
    attr(rval, "p.value") <- ifelse(p.value<0.01,"p-value\n < 0.01",paste("p-value =\n" ,format.pval(p.value)))
    return(rval)
}, class = "grapcon_generator")
```

Then substitute these functions to the corresponding `vcd` functions:

```
assignInNamespace("legend_resbased", legend_resbased, pos="package:vcd")
assignInNamespace("shading_hcl", shading_hcl, pos="package:vcd")
```

and run:

```
p <- cotabplot(~ memory + attitude | age + education, data = pun, panel = 
               cotab_coindep, n = 5000, type = "assoc", test = "maxchisq",
               interpolate = 1:2, legend = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Worked very well. For me modifying legend_resbased  alone seems to do the trick, though.